# How to count total objects in a django model

Tags: django, object, count

I am trying to get a total number of items in my model which I will be displaying in my base template as a footer. here's my code. After applying this code my HTML template does not show me the value of the total items but also it didn't show any error too.

VIEW:

```
def showthis(request):
    
    count= Item.objects.all().count()
    
    context= {'count': count}
        
    return render(request, 'waqart/footer.html', context)
```

TEMPLATE:

```
<h1 class="text-4xl md:text-6xl text-gray-700 font-semibold">UX/UI Components {{count}}</h1>
```

Comment: And what is the problem then?...

Comment: `count = Item.objects.count()` in your views. `{{ count }}` in template

Comment: Exactly what is the issue?

Comment: the HTML template does not show the value when I use this {{ count }}

Comment: What does it show instead? Does it at least render the footer?

Comment: Yes it render the footer and load other HTML elements except the count

Comment: I know this sounds stupid, but try saving the page, and then opening it on incognito, cause sometimes the html and javascript doesnt update properly, 

2. You could also try using print(count) in your function to see if there is actually some value that is being printed , (you can see the output in your command line)

Comment: I did that too but no luck. The print statement is printing below.     
<QuerySet [<Item: This is first post>, <Item: Another one>, <Item: testing size>, <Item: forth item by waqas>, <Item: hello>]>

Comment: my print code: items = Item.objects.all()
    print(items.count())

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be solved like this
view:

```
def showthis(request):
    
    item= Item.objects.all()

    context= {'item': item , 'item_count':len(item)}
        
    return render(request, 'waqart/footer.html', context)
```

and you template :

```
<h1 class="text-4xl md:text-6xl text-gray-700 font-semibold">UX/UI Components {{item_count}}</h1>
```

And another way
template :

```
<h1 class="text-4xl md:text-6xl text-gray-700 font-semibold">UX/UI Components {{item.count}}</h1>
```

Comment: thanks for this but sadly no luck still with both approach

Comment: What happens to your template after executing this code?

Comment: it renders with other static informations but the counter does not show any value

Comment: this code is true maybe your models is incorrect or import model in your view , but see this site maybe help for you https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#variables